# Is there an API to patch a POJO?

Tags: java

I have 2 instances of a class. I would like to patch one instance on to another - in restful web services sense (if a property in source POJO is not null, update its value in destination POJO else leave the property value un-touched in destination POJO). Is there an readily available API (like in Apache commons) that can do this? I would like to avoid:

1. Traverse the object graph
2. Do null checks for each and every property

Thanks!!!

Comment: Any general approach to do this generally would have to be reflective and would probably be somewhat slow as a result.

Answer (score 2):

You could try java-object-diff:
https://github.com/SQiShER/java-object-diff

It looks like a pretty active and full featured library although I have not tried it personally